# Testing route method in Angular unit test returns type error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am working on Angular application in which I am writing unit test. I have one method in my component.

MyComponent:

```
route(element) {
    this.myService.Name(element.Name);
    this.myService.Code(element.Code);
    this.router.navigate(["myPage"], { relativeTo: this.routes});
}
```

MyService:

```
Name(data) {
    this.name.next(data);
}

Code(data) {
    this.code.next(data);
}

private code = new BehaviorSubject("");
getCode = this.code.asObservable();

private name= new BehaviorSubject("");
getName = this.name.asObservable();
```

My unit test is as follows:

```
it('route() function should be called', () => {
    component.route(mockData[0]);
    var spy = spyOn(component, "route").and.callThrough();
    expect(spy).toBeDefined();
})
```

I am getting following error on running test case:

> TypeError: this.myService.Name is not a function

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have to mock `myService`. Do you have a `TestBed.configureTestingModule`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a test module into the `TestBed` in the test file, then provide your service into it by adding the service class into the providers array.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useValue: MyService }
  ]
});
```

you can even fake the service under test by passing another class to the `useValue` propriety.  that mimics the original behavior for testing proposes only.

For more information please read [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios)